# List containing specific element

Tags: java, list, recursion, stack-overflow

I have a class and one method called contains- Checks whether the list contains the given item. I get a StackOverflow error and want to know why.

I created the list and added 5 strings to the list. I am checking if one of the string elements are in the list (true if so, false if not)

```
 package arraylist_linkedList;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;

  /**
 * WordList is a singly linked list of Strings. It is designed to      demonstrate
  * how linked structures work.
  * 
  * @author ..........
  */
   public class WordList {
private Node head;
private Node tail;
private int n; // number of words in the list
static WordList list = new WordList();
/**
 * Node of LinkedList that stores the item and a single reference to the next
 * node.
 */
private class Node {
    private String item;
    private Node next;
}

/**
 * Adds a node containing the new item at the end of the list.
 * 
 * @param newItem
 */
public void append(String newItem) {
    // create a new node based on the word provided by the user
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.item = newItem;

    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    } else {
        tail.next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    n++;
}

/**
 * Adds a node containing the new item at the front of the list.
 * 
 * @param newItem
 */
public void prepend(String newItem) {
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.item = newItem;
    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
    n++;

    if (tail == null) {
        tail = head;
    }
    n++;
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified item. If the
 * specified item in not part of the list the method indexOf returns -1
 * 
 * @param item
 * @return index of the first occurrence of the item; -1 if the word was not
 *         found.
 */
public int indexOf(String item) {

    return -1; // TODO 3
}

/**
 * Checks whether the list contains the given item.
 * 
 * @param item
 * @return true if the item is contained in the list; false otherwise.
 */
public boolean contains(String item) {
    if (list.contains(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false; // TODO
}

/**
 * Returns the number of elements in the list
 * 
 * @return the number of elements
 */
public int size() {
    return n;
}

/**
 * Determines whether the list is empty or not.
 * 
 * @return true if there are no elements in the list.
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return n == 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Node current = head;

    while (current != null) {
        sb.append(current.item).append(" ");
        current = current.next;
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

/* * * * * * * * Test Client * * * * * * */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //print the list 
    System.out.println("size: " + list.size());

    // print The list is empty. or The list is not empty.
    // use a ternary operator to check whether the list is empty
    System.out.println(list.isEmpty() ? "List is empty" : "List is not empty" );

    // add words to list
    list.append("ant");
    list.append("bat");
    list.append("cow");
    list.append("dog");

    //print list 
    System.out.println("list: " + list);

    //add new item at the front of the list
    list.prepend("mouse");
    System.out.println("list: " + list);

    System.out.println("list contains: " + list.contains("ant"));



}

  }
```

error messages:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at arraylist_linkedList.WordList.contains(WordList.java:83)

Comment: `if (list.contains(item)) {` this is recursion and there is nothing to "break" it. Why are you calling `contains` **in** `contains`?

Comment: I'm new using contains is there another method that checks if a specific element such as "ant" is in the list?

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` in any non-static method.

Comment: @user9676458363 I think the trick of the the task is to write it by yourself ;) You should iterate over the nodes in your list until you reach your tail and check if one of the items matches the item you are searching for.

Comment: I thought of doing a for or for each loop but couldn't figure it out exactly. I'm new using nodes. is there a link you'd recommend i look at?

Comment: @user9676458363 Just search for `Singly Linked List`. That's a basic task every CS student will have to do. But here is the basic concept how the contains will work: Start at the `head` of the list. While the `item` of the current node isn't the `item` you are looking for, continue iterating through your list until you find the `item` or you reach the `tail` of your list.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
public boolean contains(String item) {
   if (list.contains(item))
```

On your `WordList` instance, you invoke `contains()`. That method ...turns to the **one** static `WordList` that it contains itself, and calls `contains()` again. And again, ...

You created an endless recursion here. How to implement a better solution depends on what exactly you intend to achieve. Most likely, your starting point:

```
static WordList list = new WordList();
```

is already "wrong". You imported ArrayList, so why is your `list` not an `ArrayList` for example?! In any case, it doesn't make sense at all that this list is *static*, btw.

So: your "per object" (not static) `list()` method calls "itself" on that one *static* list field of your class. That can't work, and doesn't make sense conceptually.

Comment: i used static so that I could have access to the list in the test client and public methods. What is a better way to call access to the list if I just have the WordList list = new WordList(); in test client?

Comment: @user9676458363 The better way would be to **not** make that internal list visible to the outside. And: your main should create its **own** WordList instance, and only call methods on that object. And the WordList implementation keeps track of the objects it owns all by itself.

Comment: what would that look like do you have an example

Comment: @user9676458363 That really depends on your exact requirements for your homework. But please understand: this place isnt intended to do you homework for you. You should step back, and re-read your assignment. Then talk to your peers, or maybe instructors. You can also use a search engine to identify many examples of list implementations. As said: your current code is confusing. You are importing the existing ArrayList, and then you have a Node class that suggests you intend to do a **linked list** implementation. So you should really first get clear *what* you want to do.

Comment: Examples for linked lists are all over the place: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/ ...